# After updating Fargate TaskDefinition, CloudWatch events that trigger tasks fail because of inactive task definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a series of tasks defined in ECS that run on a recurring schedule. I recently made a minor change to update my task definition in Terraform to change default environment variables for my container (from `DEBUG` to `PRODUCTION`):

```
        "environment": [
              {"name": "ENVIRONMENT", "value": "PRODUCTION"}
              ]
```

I had this task running using the `Scheduled Tasks` feature of Fargate, setting it at a rate of every 4 hours. However, after updating my task definition, I began to see that the tasks were not being triggered by CloudWatch, since my last container log was from several days ago.

I dug deeper into the issue using CloudTrail, and noticed one particular part of the entry for a `RunTask` event:

```
"eventTime": "2018-12-10T17:26:46Z",
"eventSource": "ecs.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "RunTask",
"awsRegion": "us-east-1",
"sourceIPAddress": "events.amazonaws.com",
"userAgent": "events.amazonaws.com",
"errorCode": "InvalidParameterException",
"errorMessage": "TaskDefinition is inactive",
```

Further down in the log, I noticed that the task definition ECS was attempting to run was

```
 "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXX:task-
definition/important-task-name:2",
```

However, in my ECS task definitions, the latest version of `important-task-name` was 3. So it looks like the events are not triggering because I am using an "inactive" version of my task definition.

Is there any way for me to schedule tasks in AWS Fargate without having to manually go through the console and stop/restart/update each cluster's scheduled update? Isn't there any way to simply ask CloudWatch to pull the latest active task definition?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MatheusIanzer no I did not

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudWatch Event Rules to control scheduled tasks and whenever you update a task definition you can also update your rule. Say you have two files:

myRule.json

```
{
  "Name": "run-every-minute",
  "ScheduleExpression": "cron(0/1 * * * ? *)",
  "State": "ENABLED",
  "Description": "a task that will run every minute",
  "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::${IAM_NUMBER}:role/ecsEventsRole",
  "EventBusName": "default"
}
```

myTargets.json

```
{
  "Rule": "run-every-minute",
  "Targets": [
      {
          "Id": "scheduled-task-example",
          "Arn": "arn:aws:ecs:${REGION}:${IAM_NUMBER}:cluster/mycluster",
          "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::${IAM_NUMBER}:role/ecsEventsRole",
          "Input": "{\"containerOverrides\":[{\"name\":\"myTask\",\"environment\":[{\"name\":\"ENVIRONMENT\",\"value\":\"production\"},{\"name\":\"foo\",\"value\":\"bar\"}]}]}",
          "EcsParameters": {
            "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:${REGION}:${IAM_NUMBER}:task-definition/myTaskDefinition",
            "TaskCount": 1,
            "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
            "NetworkConfiguration": {
                "awsvpcConfiguration": {
                    "Subnets": [
                        "subnet-xyz1",
                        "subnet-xyz2",
                    ],
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        "sg-xyz"
                    ],
                    "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
                }
            },
            "PlatformVersion": "LATEST"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Now, whenever there's a new revision of myTaskDefinition you may update your rule, e.g.:

```sh
aws events put-rule --cli-input-json file://myRule.json --region $REGION
aws events put-targets --cli-input-json file://myTargets.json --region $REGION
echo 'done'
```

But of course, replace IAM_NUMBER and REGION with your credentials,

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Map seems like a solution for these types of problems.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-fargate-and-amazon-ecs-now-integrate-with-aws-cloud-map/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.